# Formula Assistance to subtract a certain number based on the code IF?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to subtract a certain amount based on which code is in column H.

```
If 97530 then minus 96.40
If 92610 then

If 92507 and 92526 then
```

I know how to create my calculation formula but I can’t for the life of me figure out how to make excel look at the cell and determine appropriate amount to deduct, not me!

[image]

Comment: It seems you must use `VLOOKUP()`. The only point - you must divide rows with codes like `value1/value2` to two separate rows.

Comment: Yikes.... this report is pulled from my electronic medical record and making all those columns might be harder than manually copying and pasting formula? I need this at minimum once a week for lots and lots of claims.

Comment: What a problem? parse this `code-discount` table (if it is not static from file to file) into out-of-screen cells, separate temporary worksheet or ever in separate workbook, and use it in the formula.

Comment: Additionally. As I can see on your example worksheet, complex code values in `H2:H9` and in `H12:H19` differs only in separator char (no records where in the first region we have single value which is a part of comples value in second region, and backward). If so you may simply edit 1st region, replace slash with comma (like in 2nd) and, if needed, swap values (see rows 7 and 17), then use `VLOOKUP()`.

Answer (score 0):

The following `IF` should work for you assuming you put it in column `I`:

```
=IF(H2=97530,VLOOKUP(H2,H12:I19,2,0)-96.4,IF(H2=92610,TRUE(),FALSE()))
```

You have only provide part of your conditionals so this `IF` only matches your first requirement but it should give you a clue on the route to take.

Answer (score 0):

Jessie,

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, it looks like a VLOOKUP will work with out splitting up the information in column H. The only thing you need to do is make sure the values in the lookup table match the values it's being run against.

In this case you need to insure the Both item in either the table are change (likely the case or in the report) i.e 92610/92523 should become 92610, 92523 and 92507/92526 92526, 92507 above so the lookup will work.

[image]

The values you show seem to have an additional item added to the formula except cell K19.

The formula there would be `=VLOOKUP(H19,$H$2:$K$9,4,0)`. This will put the value 96.4 in K19. What ever this additional item is you will have to add to the above formula.

I hope this helps,
Brad

Comment: BRAD! You did it. Thanks!

Comment: @JessieOT Don't forget to accept this if it solved your issue!